# Does phone battery last longer if I charge often or less frequently?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

Which practice will help my Android phone lithium battery last longer?

- Charge often. Whenever phone battery drops to, say, 70%, charge it back to full 100%.
- Charge less frequently. Charge phone to full 100% after it has dropped to between 0% to 20%.

An explanation for the choice would be helpful.

Comment: Different batteries age at different rates when sitting idle, when deep cycled and when shallow cycled. Even for the same battery aging also depends very strongly on temperature (lower is better up until a point). The manufacturer of your battery probably has a good idea of how to answer your question, but I doubt anyone here can provide an authorative answer.

Comment: If you are charging often then is that because the phone battery needs charging? If you are charging less frequently is that because the the battery is lasting longer?

Answer (score 1):

The number of cycles and sitting too high or low is what matters. The number of times you decide to plug in the battery doesn't mean anything.

First is worse not because you plug it in more (you're not charging it more). It is worse because you are maintaining the voltage too high.

Comment: I've disagreed wit your answer in this case. I usually don't :-). You may wish to look at my  answer  - any comment is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I'll disagree with DKNguyen even though his answers are usually good.

In this case the greater depth of cycle of the infrequent charge method places greater mechanical stress on the battery cell structure.

A major component of LiIon battery failure is mechanical cycling of the cell as it is charged/discharged. (The LiFePO4 battery has a greater cycle life due to the solid Olivine structure which does not change shape/size as Li ions are passed to and fro.
So recharging from 70% charged is better.

Best of all is not to approach either extreme too closely.
About 20% to 80% is good but harder to manage.

Stopping when Vbat reaches 4.2V with no constant voltage mode  is also good but also hard to achieve with a std charger.

Comment: I agree sitting very low (<10% or so) is worse than sitting very high, but I'm assuming the OP will charge to 100% every time and let it sit there longer while not let it run that low most of the time before he decides to charge.

Answer (score 1):

### Use your Li-ion battery in 20% - 80% SoC range at room temperature.

The performance of a battery is measured via its delivered [capacity](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/battery_definitions) (Ah), which is the best indicator out of many other parameters, the capacity decides the run-time of the application in use.

> The SoC range is not 0% - 100% above because a partial charge and discharge reduces stress on the battery material and prolongs its life.

Alos keeping the battery at < 10% for longer duration can lead to a faster capacity (Ah) drop.

As most consumers don't bother with these things and these things are hard to control, manufacturers use higher capacity rated batteries and claim lower than that to maintain user satisfaction and avoid warranty claims in some cases.

For more detailed explanation and tested data go to [this link](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries)